# Does Firestore download all the documents on getDocuments()

Tags: ios, swift, google-cloud-firestore

I'm using getDocuments() to get all the documents in a collection. Does Firestore "download" all the documents each time or it only downloads the changed documents and the unchanged ones are retrieved from the local cache of Firestore?

Answer (score 1):

If [local persistence](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/enable-offline) is enabled in your app (it is by default on iOS), then unchanged documents will not be downloaded again.